# Is there a formula for $\prod_0^{p-1}(x+k)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm working on another problem and being able to calculate a polynomial product like $$\prod_{k=0}^{p-1}(x+k)$$ would help a lot. If it helps I only really need it for characteristic $p$, but now I'm curious if something holds in general. I tried writing out the product up to 5, but I'm not seeing a pattern if there even is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In characteristic $p$ this is well known to simplify to $x^p-x$. By little Fermat all the entries $k=0,1,\ldots,p-1$ are zeros of $x^p-x$. Therefore $x+k=x-(p-k)$ is a factor. Because there are $p$ factors, and $x^p-x$ is monic of degree $p$, we can conclude.

Comment: See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Definitions.2C_first_examples.2C_and_basic_properties). One of the more often used facts in characteristic $p$ algebra.

Comment: Ah thank you, this is actually of the form I wanted. I always forget Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an asymptotic estimate
(which may not be what you
are looking for):

If
$u = x+\frac{p-1}{2}$
then
$\prod_{k=0}^{p-1}(x+k)
=u^p-\frac{n^3-n}{24}u^{p-2}
+O(u^{p-3})
$.

I can send you the paper
where I prove this.

Comment: Unfortunately its not too helpful, but thank you for the answer. Are asymptotics the best that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

This product is called the [rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials), and the coefficients are given by the [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).  There are many formulas and identities for these numbers, but no simple closed form.